# Is there any difference between for loop in java and c?

Tags: java, c, for-loop, iteration

**for loop in c**

```
int i;
int n = 20;
for(i = 0; i + n; i-- ) {
     printf("-\n");

}
```

**for loop in java**

```
int i;
int n=20;
for (i = 0; i + n; i--) {
   System.out.println("-\n");
}
```

In the above example for loop in c is working fine(will print "-" 20 times).But for loop in java shows error as

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean**

why it shows this kind of error?

Comment: you do not have to declare i before the loop

Comment: @DnR why would I need it? Only if I have to access i after the loop, and he does not. And btw, I do not understand his break condition as well. never seen that in java. but there is already an answer for that

Comment: @ZerO `i` accessed just after the loop begin. it is not wrong to declare `i` like that instead of `for (int i = 0; i + n; i--)`

Comment: I just tried without declaring i before the loop.but it is not working..

Comment: In the original version of C, you couldn't write `for (int i = 0;...` - you had to declare it before.  I think that C has since been updated to allow this construct, but I'm not sure, as it is many years since I have programmed in C.

Comment: @Sana of course. any variable must be declared before you can use it. Ignore the comment and take a look at the answers below

Comment: Not sure if you got what I was talking about. In Java, you do NOT have to declare it before the loop. And that is what I wrote. I have no idea why you claim that I said that it would be wrong in any way...

Comment: @ZerO: prior to C99, `for (int i` was illegal. Now, you can declare an int in a loop, but be advised: the variable will be GC'ed the moment the loop ends.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C, `0` is considered `false` and the rest of number are interpreted as `true`. In Java, this doesn't work since it has a `boolean` type that is not an `int`, and an `int` cannot be directly converted into a `boolean`.

To fix the Java code, you should write the second part as a `boolean` expression:

```
for (i = 0; (i + n) != 0; i--) {
    System.out.println("-\n");
}
```

While `(i + n) != 0` may work, I would prefer to use `(i + n) > 0`, because if `n` starts at `-1`, this loop will work until `i` goes down to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` value, underflows to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and go down to `1`. To prevent that behavior (in case is undesired), it would be better to write it like this:

```
for (i = 0; (i + n) > 0; i--) {
    System.out.println("-\n");
}
```

From @Lundin's comment, looks like your C code should be fixed as well:

```
//or use my proposed fix by using > rather than !=
for(i = 0; (i + n) != 0; i-- ) {
    printf("-\n");
}
```

Comment: In C, I believe any *nonzero* value is true (not just positive numbers)

Comment: To keep control statements as "effectively" boolean is recommended practice in C as well. So not only the Java code should be corrected as shown here, but also the C code! This is for example required by MISRA-C.

Answer (score 3):

The original version of C didn't have booleans, so everyone used integers instead.  The language would interpret anything non-zero as true, and zero as false.

But Java is stricter about what's a boolean and what's an integer - you actually need to use a boolean expression (such as `i + n != 0`) to check whether the loop should continue.